# Batch script that hides all items in folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, hide

I want to create a small .bat file that will hide all items in one specific folder (actually add attributes +s and +h to them), but I am not really good at scripting so I need your help.

Thanks in advance.

edit: I don't want folder to be hidden, but just all items inside it.

Comment: Take away or eat here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job and hides folders also.

```
attrib +s +h "c:\folder\*.*" /D
```

Comment: Thanks, it hides all files, shortcuts etc. but I need it to hide directories that are inside that directory as well.

Comment: Thanks, I had to add /S as well, but yeah, it works!

Answer (score 2):

use `dir /A /D`, the result gives all directory names enclosed in [] and file name without []. Loop through all the names which are not enclosed within [] and set the attribute using `attrib +s +h`

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a /b "c:\somewhere\*"') do attrib +h +s "%%~fa"
```